# How to fetch name in one table according to the max tax payed in other table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have these two tables,

```
 employeeid | firstname  | lastname |   address   | pan  |  joindate  | lastupdatedate | annualincome | taxrate | currentgrade 
------------+------------+----------+-------------+------+------------+----------------+--------------+---------+--------------
          1 | tushar     | mishra   | bommanhalli | ab7c | 2012-10-15 |                |       300000 |    0.05 |            2
          2 | puneet     | purohit  | j.p         | ab5c | 2012-10-15 |                |       300000 |    0.05 |            2
          3 | vishwanath | b.s      | btm         | ab6c | 2012-10-15 |                |       300000 |    0.05 |            1
          4 | xavier     | d'souza  | btm         | ab8c | 2012-10-15 |                |       300000 |    0.05 |            1
          5 | deepak     | kumar    | hebbal      |      | 2012-10-15 |                |       300000 |    0.05 |            1
```

and other one..

```
employeeid | salarydate | income | tax  
------------+------------+--------+------
          2 | 2012-11-01 |  25000 | 1250
          3 | 2012-11-01 |  25000 | 1250
          4 | 2012-11-01 |  25000 | 1250
          5 | 2012-11-01 |  25000 | 1250
          2 | 2012-12-01 |  25000 | 1250
          3 | 2012-12-01 |  25000 | 1250
          4 | 2012-12-01 |  25000 | 1250
          5 | 2012-12-01 |  25000 | 1250
          2 | 2013-01-01 |  25000 | 1250
          3 | 2013-01-01 |  25000 | 1250
          4 | 2013-01-01 |  25000 | 1250
          5 | 2013-01-01 |  25000 | 1250
          1 | 2012-11-01 |  25000 | 1500
          1 | 2012-12-01 |  25000 | 1500
          1 | 2013-01-01 |  25000 | 1500
```

here the tax column in second table is for a month .i want to fetch the name of the employee who had paid highest tax last year. here employee id in second table is referenced to the employeid in 1st table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code.

```
select salary.employeeid,firstname,lastname, sum(tax) 
 from salary
left join employee 
   on salary.employeeid=employee.employeeid
group by salary.employeeid,firstname,lastname
order by sum(tax) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

(Just noted the Postgres tag ... this is for Oracle but what the heck I'll leave it up anyway)

```
select first_name,
       last_name
from   employees
where  employee_id = (
         select   employee_id
         from     (
                  select   employee_id
                  from     salaries
                  where    salarydate >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY'),-12) and
                           salarydate <  trunc(sysdate,'YYYY')
                  group by employee_id
                  order by sum(tax_paid) desc)
         where    rownum = 1)
```